# Access to a shared folder using NTLM authentication

Tags: c#, .net, iis

I have a C# MVC web application that uses the NTML authentication (windows authentication). And I want to access to a shared folder (accessible from the web server).

the shared folder contains a list of sub directories, each directory represents a user personal directory. using windows explorer in the web server, each user is able only to access to its personal folder.

Actually, when I want to access to this shared folder using the application, I have an access denied (As the IIS process doesn't have permission to access to this folders). And I want to know how the user can access to its personal folder via the application.

Is there a way to get user login and password from NTML connection, or a way to access to this shared folder via user NTML token?

I don't have the user login/password.

Comment: What kind of share is it? To clarify, you want to access the folder as the authenticated user, not the app pool identity under IIS? If that is the case, I do not know that there's an easy way to do it.

Comment: Yes I want to access as an authenticated user. Any other suggestion are welcome. The final goal is to access to this shared folder

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/134ec8tc.aspx is helpful?

Comment: The same way as any other folder? As long as you're using ACL, the approach is pretty much the same.

Comment: It works fine in localhost and I can access to the shared folder using the application. But it doesn't work in the dev server (iis 8.5). The shared folder is accessible from this server usgin windows explorer

Answer (score 0):

You can  change the thread identity https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w070t6ka(v=vs.110).aspx
or use P/Invoke WNetAddConnection2 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385413(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I changed to identity as shown in the example but it doesn't work, I enabled also the user impersonate. It works fine in localhost and I can access to the shared folder using the application. But it doesn't work in the dev server (iis 8.5). The shared folder is accessible from this server usgin windows explorer

Answer (score 0):

You can enable ASP.NET user impersonation - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa292118(v=vs.71).aspx

However, do note that you need to make sure that you only use impersonation when accessing the user's resources - for example, if you simply impersonate the whole request, you may no longer have access to shared data or a database.

Comment: I enabled the user impersonate, and it doesn't work. I have the same error, access denied to the folder. It works fine in localhost and I can access to the shared folder using the application. But it doesn't work in the dev server (iis 8.5). The shared folder is accessible from this server usgin windows explorer

Comment: @user3540496 Are your computers in a domain?

Comment: Yes, localhost and the web server (IIS) are in the same domain